# Why in $GF(7)$ there are no nonzero elements satisfying $a^2 + b^2 = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, scalar-fields

Why in $GF(7)$ there are no nonzero elements satisfying $a^2 + b^2 = 0$? how can I know this by a quick method without calculations? Is there a theorem or something that can help here?

$GF(7)$ is the integers modulo $7.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a^2 + b^2 = 0$, and $b \ne 0$, then $(a/b)^2 = -1$, so $a/b$ has multiplicative order $4$.  Now the order of any group element divides the order of the group. In this case
the group has order $6$.  Since $4$ does not divide $6$, we're done.

Comment: why in this case the group has order 6?

Comment: The group is the nonzero elements of $GF(7)$.  There are $7-1 = 6$ of them.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists $a,b$ non-zero such that $a^{2}+b^{2}\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, then this would mean $$a^{2}\equiv -b^{2}\pmod{7}\implies \left(\frac{-1}{7}\right)=1$$ which is absurd as by [Euler's Criterion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/eulers-criterion/) we have $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=-1$ for primes congruent to $3\pmod{4}$.